# Condense Protractor Test Files

Tags: protractor

Is there a good way to condense Protractor test files? I understand there are Page Objects that define methods to be used for tests. But when writing tests themselves, there are multiple .js files for each test case. Are there any good protractor tips/ writing styles that will minimize this?

Looking for an approach like in TestNG where there are multiple test methods in a .java file that are called when defined in a file that is run by choosing desired methods.

Comment: Why are there multiple .js files for each test case?  Can you give an example?

Comment: I Agree with Bill Poitras. I am not sure what you are saying like multiple .js files @detec Su

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is not wrong, you are taking each test case in several files.
Instead of that, you can have n number of test cases in a single file.

You can write spec file like this.

```
describe('your parent test page', function(){
   describe('inner functionality group', function(){
      it('your actual test cases' , function(){

        });
      .
      .
      .
      n number of it();
   });
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   n number of describe();

});
```

Still, if you want to group your test cases from single Spec file, you can use exports like this.

Parent file will be like:

```
describe('your parent test page', function(){
       var childTestPage = require(<relative path to the file>);
       describe('inner functionality group', function(){
          it('your actual test cases' , function(){

            });
       });
       childTestPage.start();
    });
```

Child Page as:

```
exports.start = function(){
  describe('your new test cases', function(){
});
};
```